# MVVM binding with design time data works correctly at design time, but not at run time

Tags: vb.net, mvvm

I have a simple MVVM project with design time data which works fine with both the main data and a listbox with user controls for each of the child items.
However when I instantiate the classes at run time, the the master data displays however the child data does not display (but the listbox has the correct number of items, however they don't have any of the data displaying in the textboxes ).

I have noticed the constructor on Sport gets called far to many times, compared to what I'd expect (e.g. at run time, I'd expect it to be called only twice, but it seems to be called more than that).

I have class Person, and Sport. Every person can like multiple sports and have a favorite team.
I have a personViewModel & sportViewModel which inherit from viewModelBase.

Here is my VB.net Code

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class Person
    Public Property Forename As String
    Public Property Surname As String
    Public Sports As New ObservableCollection(Of Sport)
End Class


Public Class Sport
    Public Sub New()
        Debug.WriteLine("test")
    End Sub

    Public Property SportName As String
    Public Property FavouriteProfessionalTeam As String
End Class


Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Namespace ViewModel

    Public Class PersonViewModel
        Inherits ViewModel.ViewModelBase

        Public Property Person1 As Person
        Public Property SportViewModels As New ObservableCollection(Of SportViewModel)

        Public Sub New()
            LoadData()
        End Sub

        ''' <summary> 
        ''' Loads the data for the application. 
        ''' </summary> 
        Private Sub LoadData()
            If IsInDesignModeStatic Then
                LoadDesignData()
            Else

            End If
        End Sub

        ''' <summary> 
        ''' Loads temporary data for use in the designer. 
        ''' </summary> 
        Private Sub LoadDesignData()
            Person1 = New Person
            Person1.Forename = "Mickey Run Time"
            Person1.Surname = "Mouse Run Time"

            Person1.Sports.Add(New Sport With {.FavouriteProfessionalTeam = "Man Utd", .SportName = "Soccer"})
            Person1.Sports.Add(New Sport With {.FavouriteProfessionalTeam = "Barcelona", .SportName = "Spanish Soccer"})
            Person1.Sports.Add(New Sport With {.FavouriteProfessionalTeam = "Ulster", .SportName = "Rugby"})

            For Each sport1 In Person1.Sports
                Dim sportVm As New SportViewModel With {.Sport1 = sport1}
                SportViewModels.Add(sportVm)
            Next

        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace ViewModel
    Public Class SportViewModel
        Inherits ViewModel.ViewModelBase

        Public Property Sport1 As New Sport
        Public Property Person1 As Person

        Public Sub New()
            LoadData()
        End Sub

        ''' <summary> 
        ''' Loads the data for the application. 
        ''' </summary> 
        Private Sub LoadData()
            If IsInDesignModeStatic Then
                LoadDesignData()
            Else
                ' Debug.WriteLine(Sport1.SportName)
                ' Load the student data asynchronously 
                'StudentContextInstance = New StudentContext
                'Dim loadop =
                '  StudentContextInstance.Load(StudentContextInstance.
                '             GetStudentsQuery(),
                '             AddressOf OnStudentsLoaded, Nothing)
            End If
        End Sub

        ''' <summary> 
        ''' Loads temporary data for use in the designer. 
        ''' </summary> 
        Private Sub LoadDesignData()
            Sport1 = New Sport With {.SportName = "Design Time Name", .FavouriteProfessionalTeam = "Design Time Team"}
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace

Imports System.ComponentModel

Namespace ViewModel

    Public Class ViewModelBase
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
        Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        Private Shared _isInDesignMode As Boolean?
        Public Shared ReadOnly Property IsInDesignModeStatic As Boolean
            Get
                If Not _IsInDesignMode.HasValue Then
                    _IsInDesignMode = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(New DependencyObject)
                End If
                Return _IsInDesignMode.Value
            End Get
        End Property


        Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
            ' Send an event notification that the property changed 
            ' This allows the UI to know when one of the items changes 
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) Then
                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me,
                                           New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
            End If
        End Sub



    End Class
End Namespace
```

Here is the code behind for my wain window which sets up the MVVM for display
    Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
    Imports WpfApplicationMVVMTest.ViewModel

```
Class MainWindow
    Public Property Person1 As Person
    Public Property SportViewModels As New ObservableCollection(Of SportViewModel)
    Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim wndPerson As New PersonWindow


        Person1 = New Person
        Person1.Forename = "Donald"
        Person1.Surname = "Duck"

        Person1.Sports.Add(New Sport With {.FavouriteProfessionalTeam = "Man Utd", .SportName = "Soccer"})
        Person1.Sports.Add(New Sport With {.FavouriteProfessionalTeam = "Barcelona", .SportName = "Spanish Soccer"})

        For Each sport1 In Person1.Sports
            Dim sportVm As New SportViewModel With {.Sport1 = sport1}
            SportViewModels.Add(sportVm)
        Next




        Dim vm As New ViewModel.PersonViewModel
        vm.SportViewModels = SportViewModels
        vm.Person1 = Person1
        wndPerson.DataContext = vm
        wndPerson.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the XAML Code

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationMVVMTest.ViewModel"
    xmlns:View="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationMVVMTest" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="PersonWindow"
    Title="PersonWindow" Height="1114.8" Width="542">
    <Window.Resources></Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:PersonViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="Grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Forename:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="ForenameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Person1.Forename, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
            <Label Content="Surname:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="SurnameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Person1.Surname, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
        </Grid>
        <ListBox Margin="41,108,59,753" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SportViewModels}"  >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <View:SportUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"  Margin="5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>

<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationMVVMTest.ViewModel" x:Class="SportUserControl" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <UserControl.Resources></UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:SportViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>


    <Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="Grid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Content="Favourite Professional Team:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="FavouriteProfessionalTeamTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Sport1.FavouriteProfessionalTeam, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
            <Label Content="Sport Name:" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="SportNameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="3" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Sport1.SportName, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my design time image with 3 Sports displayed (as per my load design time data).
[image]

Here is my run time window with 2 sports displaying (although they have no data - which is the issue).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting Datacontexts in your mark up and in code...remove the markup and stick to one pattern

Comment: many thanks, just for a fuller explanation of what I did following your comment:
I commented this code out in the SportsView User Control
<!--<UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:SportViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>-->

Comment: Also just to confirm the side effects of doing this. The SportView no longer shows design time data on it's own. However it does show design time data when it is displayed on the PersonView Listbox.

Comment: just found a way to do this so it works for even the sub view, can use d:DataContext so that only gets set at design time: d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:ViewModalThatYouWantToUse, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"